# Authenticate to Google with Oauth2 in JMeter

Tags: oauth, google-drive-api, jmeter, google-oauth

I am making a POST call to get oAuth token in JMeter. So that I can upload files to Google Drive. Below is my request details in JMeter.

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

POST data:
client_id=<my_client_id>&auth_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Fauth&token_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Ftoken&client_secret=<my_client_secret>&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uris=%5B%22urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob%22%2C+%22127.0.0.1%3A3000%22%5D%0A&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 424
Host: accounts.google.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_121)
```

But I am getting below error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
{
:   
  "error" 
:   : "invalid_request",

:   "error_description" : "Missing required parameter: code"

}
```

Comment: Will this be helpful for you? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: I checked this. But couldn't able to build the request in JMeter.

Comment: If you want to upload files, an access token is required. If you want to retrieve the access token, a code retrieved from URL with scopes is required.

Comment: Are you using JMeter to run tests and is the Drive Account you're using a test account for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not help you with JMeter but I can tell you what the error message means.

The `grant_type=authorization_code` is the second step in the Oauth2 flow. It has a few required parameters one of them is code.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

The code in question is the code that was returned from the initial request for the user to approve the applications access.

I would also like to add that Google has a number of official client libraries that will deal with these calls for you.  Using one of those is much easer then trying to understand the Oauth2 flow if you don't need to.   If you cant use the library and you are interested in seeing the full Oauth2 flow to google I have a tutorial on it [Google 3 legged Oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/) it shows the pure HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Google OAuth Java Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/) from [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) using [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as a programming language, this is the fastest and the easiest way to obtain/refresh OAuth tokens.

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for detailed explanation and an authorization example.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I was checking your article https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter where you directly entered the Bearer {token}.

Can you please let me know how you obtained that token manually?

Comment: Any chance you want to add some code to this show him how to use the Library other wise IMO this is board line link only answer.